# Setting navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES never shows my navbar again

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When i set `navigationController.hidesBarOnSwipe = YES` and try swiping in the webView shown the navigation bar is hidden, but it will never show up again, when i try swiping to get it back.

My ViewController is listening to the swipe event :

```
[self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)]?
```

But this selector is in fact never called again after the navigation bar is hidden because of the Swipe. Anyone implemented `hidesBarOnSwipe`? Is it a known bug or is it as designed that it won't show the navigation bar after hiding it.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I have noticed that if I have a UIViewController with a tableView I get the issue you are describing.  However if I instead use a UITableViewController, the problem goes away.

Comment: @haaakon were you able to solve this? I'm having the same problem, I'm using a WKWebView initialised through code but have so far been unable to resolve it by setting layout constraints on the view.

Comment: @HenrikHartz i think i used a cocoapod that specifically handles this.

Comment: Ok, you can't remember which by any chance? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same problem with my `UIWebView`, It's fixed by updating the constrains of my `WebView` to be relative to the superview not layout guide:

[image]

Comment: That's it, but unfortunately it only works with a distance of '0'. I think I'll check for one of the 3rdparty alternatives like https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar instead.

Comment: Is there any solution to use this with other distance(constraint.const) than 0 ?

Comment: Had to update my app that I haven't touched for 2 years. Loading the project in Xcode 9.3 started giving me this problem, but problem does not appear when you download the live app. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem where the navigation bar did not show even after I set the `hidesBarOnSwipe` to `NO`.  Adding the following line fixed it for me (after setting `hidesBarOnSwipe` to `NO`)

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS 15.