# Navigation Bar doesn't come back once it hides (swipe)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I created a ViewController with TableView inside it and embedded it a NavigationController. I also set the constraints. On Swipe down, Navigation Bar hides. Everything seems fine.

The only problem is that on Swipe Up, the Navigation Bar doesn't come back.

If I use the same TableView with a TableViewController instead of ViewController (embedded from the same Navigation Controller), the Navigation Bar does comes back.

---

*For the ones wondering why I don't just go with the TableViewController, because I need to uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets for some disturbing  [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510974/on-navbar-swipe-hide-headercell-creates-a-transparent-gap-and-content-appears-t).*

Comment: Maybe you should post some code.

Comment: It was done from the Storyboard.

Comment: it seems like this same issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/24710258/4975761

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES never shows my navbar again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524395/setting-navigationcontroller-hidesbarsonswipe-yes-never-shows-my-navbar-again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the issue, I used `scrollViewWillEndDragging` and detected `Going Down` & `Going Up`

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

   if targetContentOffset.memory.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
       // UP
   } else {
       // DOWN
   }
}
```

Comment: If you test for negative velocity, you can set a threshold speed to make the NavBar reappear. That way the user can control when the NavBar appears.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, based on senty's answer:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let draggDelta = scrollView.contentOffset.y - targetContentOffset.pointee.y

    let hiddenContentHeight = spreadsheetView.contentSize.height - spreadsheetView.frame.height - 1

    if 0 < draggDelta && targetContentOffset.pointee.y < hiddenContentHeight || (targetContentOffset.pointee.y == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {

        // Shows Navigation Bar
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```